# Which package changes the hyperref \newlabel hyperanchor for figures to include figure.caption and how do I reverse it?

Tags: hyperref

Which package affects the hyperref `\theHfigure` label value? How can I reverse this?

I was hoping to change the `hyperref counter-specific label` using

```
\renewcommand*{\theHfigure}{runningfigurecounter.\the\value{runningfigurecounter}}
```

but to my surprise, the `.aux` file does not contain the label as expected. Rather, the 4th parameter (the label) of the 2nd parameter of `\newlabel` which generally looks like this

```
\newlabel{figure:somelabel}{{1}{1}{A title}{hyperref counter-specific label}{random parameter that is empty until the cows home}}
```

contains contains something like this:

```
figure.caption.5
```

Expected was this:

```
runningfigurecounter.5
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Running Counter
\newcounter{runningfigurecounter}

% Redefine hyperref \newlabel counters for unique targets with disregard for the printed form
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{runningfigurecounter.\the\value{runningfigurecounter}}

% Apply \refstepcounter in macros called in the document
\let\oldfigure\figure
\renewcommand{\figure}{\refstepcounter{runningfigurecounter}\oldfigure}


% Counter For TeX Loop (these are not global)
\newcount\STEP
\newcount\STEPTOTAL
\STEPTOTAL=5

\begin{document}

References:
\STEP=0
\loop
\advance\STEP 1
\ref{fig:\the\STEP}
\ifnum\STEP<\STEPTOTAL
\repeat


% TeX Loop to Generate Figures and Labels
\STEP=0
\loop
\advance\STEP 1
\newpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt{\theHfigure}}
\label{fig:\the\STEP}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\ifnum\STEP<\STEPTOTAL
\repeat

\end{document}
```

## PDF Output Clip

[image]

## Relevant entries in the .aux

As you can see here, the entry is `figure.caption.1` (thru 5) and not `runningfigurecounter.1` (thru 5).

```
\newlabel{fig:1}{{1}{2}{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt {\theHfigure }\relax }{figure.caption.1}{}}

\newlabel{fig:2}{{2}{4}{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt {\theHfigure }\relax }{figure.caption.2}{}}

\newlabel{fig:3}{{3}{6}{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt {\theHfigure }\relax }{figure.caption.3}{}}

\newlabel{fig:4}{{4}{8}{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt {\theHfigure }\relax }{figure.caption.4}{}}

\newlabel{fig:5}{{5}{10}{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt {\theHfigure }\relax }{figure.caption.5}{}}
```

Comment: My first guess would be the `caption` package... but without seeing any line of code, it remains a guess

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right, the `caption` package is the culprit. Since nobody answered yet, I changed the question a bit to include reversing the `caption` changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `caption` package defines

```
   \renewcommand*\caption@makestart[1]{%
          \begingroup
          \Hy@hypertexnamesfalse
          \hyper@makecurrent{#1.caption}%
          \endgroup
          \caption@Debug{hypcap start=\@currentHref}}%
    }
```

which provides a prefix of the anchor name `#1.caption`, where `#1` is replaced by the current `\@captype`, i.e. `figure` here.

This should be replaced by `\hyper@makecurrent{\csname theH#1\endcsname}`, which applies the 'correct' `\theH...` macro then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% Running Counters
\newcounter{runningfigurecounter}
\newcounter{runningsectioncounter}


% Redefine hyperref \newlabel counters for unique targets with disregard for the printed form
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{runningfigurecounter.\therunningfigurecounter}

% Apply \refstepcounter in macros called in the document
\let\oldfigure\figure
\let\oldsection\section
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \refstepcounter{runningfigurecounter}%
}

% Counter For TeX Loop (these are not global)
\newcount\STEP
\newcount\STEPTOTAL
\STEPTOTAL=10

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*\caption@makestart[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \Hy@hypertexnamesfalse
      \hyper@makecurrent{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
      \endgroup
      \caption@Debug{hypcap start=\@currentHref}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


References:
\STEP=0
\loop
\advance\STEP 1
\ref{fig:\the\STEP}
\ifnum\STEP<\STEPTOTAL
\repeat


% TeX Loop to Generate Figures and Labels
\STEP=0
\loop
\advance\STEP 1
\newpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another fake picture. \textbackslash theHfigure = \texttt{\theHfigure}}
  \label{fig:\the\STEP}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\ifnum\STEP<\STEPTOTAL
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `xpatch` really necessary? Or did you just leave it in there after your tests?

Comment: I kept it accidentally

Comment: @JonathanKomar: I removed `xpatch` from loading, but replaced it with `etoolbox` for `\AtBeginEnvironment`, which is a little bit cleaner than chaning `\figure` directly

Comment: You are great :-). Hi Christian. Upvote.